gcrd and associates of an element of the quaternion algebra over a totally real number field $K$
Let $K$ be a totally real number field of class number 1, and $Q$ the quaternion algebra over the ring of integers of  $K$ with basis
$\{1,i,j,k\}$ such that $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$ and $ij = -ji, ik = -ki$ and $jk = -kj$.

my first question is does $Q$ have a gcrd algorithm?
where grcd is the greatest common right divisor.
given two associated integral elements $a,b$ , how to find all  $u \in Q$ such that $a=ub$

If so some references would be sufficient for me.

You previously asked this question on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4933504/gcrd-and-associates-of-an-element-of-the-quaternion-algebra-over-a-totally-real and then apparently deleted it.  It's okay to ask on MO also after awhile if it doesn't get answers on MSE (with cross-post links on both questions), but I'm not sure the point of deleting the MSE question.  E.g., comments on the previous question are now lost.

I thought I can not ask the same question, and it is against rule so I did ask here
should I undeleted and is it okey to ask the same on other platform?

No, it's allowed if you don't get a (satisfactory) answer after some time, and this is relatively common.  See here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637/6518 (that question is about posting first to MO then MSE, but it works the same the other way around too)

thanks @Kimball and sorry for my mistake!

If I understand your question, your condition 1. implies that every right ideal of $Q$ (we usual call $Q$ an order, not an algebra) is principal. This won't hold as soon as the discriminant of $K$ is large enough, by Eichler's mass formula (regardless of the class number of $K$).

For 2., the algebra $A = K\otimes Q$ is a division algebra, so $u = ab^{-1}$ is the only solution when it exists.

Thanks @Aurel , Can I contact you via your email?

@DonFreecs Sorry for the slow response. Sure, feel free to send me an email.
